# Replace underscore with spaces for each object key in array

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript Array with multiple objects.

```
var array = [{First_name:Mike, Last_Name: Kelly},{First_Name:Charles, Last_Name:Bronson},{First_Name:Chuck, Last_Name:Norris}];
```

How can i iterate through each object and string.replace('_'g,' ') each key?
Essentially i need to replace the underscore with spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var array = [
  {First_Name: 'Mike', Last_Name: 'Kelly'},
  {First_Name: 'Charles', Last_Name: 'Bronson'},
  {First_Name: 'Chuck', Last_Name: 'Norris'},
];

function convert(obj) {
  const result = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
    result[key.replace(/_/g, ' ')] = obj[key];
  });

  return result;
}


var result = array.map(function (o) {
    return convert(o);
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (var prop in array[i]) {
        if (prop.includes("_")) {
            array[i][prop.split("_").join(" ")] = array[i][prop];
            delete array[i][prop];
        }
    }
}
```