# Replace underscore with space and capitalize first word of each key from a given array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have the following array of objects

```
var array = [
  {first_name: 'Mike', last_name: 'Kelly'},
  {first_name: 'Charles', last_name: 'Bronson'},
  {first_name: 'Chuck', last_name: 'Norris'},
];
```

I wanted to replace underscore with space and capitalize first word of each key as follows

```
var array = [
  {"First Name": 'Mike', "Last Name": 'Kelly'},
  {"First Name": 'Charles', "Last Name": 'Bronson'},
  {"First Name": 'Chuck', "Last Name": 'Norris'},
];
```

I managed to remove underscore with the following code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44704817/12499550) but I can't capitalize first letter of each keys.

```
function convert(obj) {
  const result = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
    result[key.replace(/_/g, ' ')] = obj[key];
  });

  return result;
}


var result = array.map(function (o) {
    return convert(o);
});
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you check this ? https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/JjZMqpr

Comment: @ManirajMurugan Thanks It works. Please provide your code in the answer section so hat I could accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep use another replace regex  to replace the string at the first and also after the space first letter to make upper case like,

```js
var array = [
  {first_name: 'Mike', last_lame: 'Kelly'},
  {first_Name: 'Charles', last_lame: 'Bronson'},
  {lirst_lame: 'Chuck', last_lame: 'Norris'},
];

function convert(obj) {
  const result = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    const name = key.replace(/_/g, ' ').replace(/(^\w|\s\w)(\S*)/g, (_,m1,m2) => m1.toUpperCase()+m2.toLowerCase());
    result[name] = obj[key];
  });
  return result;
}


const res = array.map((o) => convert(o));

console.log('result ', res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```js
var array = [
  {first_name: 'Mike', last_name: 'Kelly'},
  {first_name: 'Charles', last_name: 'Bronson'},
  {first_name: 'Chuck', last_name: 'Norris'},
];

const cap = str => `${str[0].toUpperCase()}${str.slice(1)}`;

const res = array.map(it => Object.entries(it).reduce((a, [k,v]) => ({...a, [(k.split("_").map(c => cap(c)).join(" "))]: v}), {}));

console.log(res);
```